# Browser permission 'Share your screen' popup not showing in kiosk mode (safe browser)

Tags: javascript, screen-capture, kiosk-mode

We have a website that uses Screen Capture API to take random screenshots of the users' desktop. In order for the Screen Capture API to work as expected, the users need to allow it and select the screen they want to share. See image bellow [image]

However the following problem occurs; 
We want the website to open using Safe Exam Browser so that users don't have access to any other files while on the website. Safe Exam Browser opens the website in kiosk mode. It seems like when the website is opened in kiosk mode, the 'Share your screen' browser popup does not show which results in users not being able to share their screen and the system can't take random screenshots.

Is there anyway to show the 'Share your screen' browser popup or somehow force the browser to automatically start sharing the screen?

Note: the above problem happens only when the browser is running in kiosk mode with the Safe Exam Browser. When the website is opened in a normal browser (not in kiosk mode), it works as expected and the  Share your screen' browser popup does show.

Comment: Not sure if this might be your issue, but localhost in Chrome is considered a secure origin,  a lot of Javascript API's don't work unless using a secure connection.  So that would explain why localhost works,.. But if the Kiosk is connecting not via localhost you might need to make sure you connect using `https`, not `http`, as certain api's are disabled in Chrome unless the connection is secure.  This of course means you would also need an SSL certificate to stop the continue to site error that would appear.

Comment: I have tested this live using https and it still does the same thing :/ Also tried it with Mozilla and the  'Share your screen' popup does not show.